# Deployed Aspnet WebApi to IIS OK but return 500 internal Server Error When CRUD

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am just starting asp.net Core 2.0 web api. Please extend your help.

I have successfully deployed the asp.net WebApi app to Local IIS and 
I have created a database in Sql Server 2017 (free version) with below code.

problem: status 500 internal server error when I do a post with PostMan

```
  1) in StartUp.cs with ConnectionString:

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
      services.AddMvc();

      services.AddDbContext<ContactContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
     }


    2) connection string in appsettings.json

    "connectionstrings": {
     "Default": "Server = .\\SQL2017Express; Database = ContactDB; Integrated Security = True;"
      }


    **The Problems Encountered:** 

    problem: status 500 internal server error when I do a post with PostMan 

    Post : http://192.168.1.8:8989/api/contacts

    Json Data for the Body in PostMan:
    {
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "David",
    "MobilePhone" : "123456789"
    }

// controller
    [Produces("application/json")]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class ContactsController : Controller
        {
            public IContactRepository ContactsRepo { get; set; }

            public ContactsController(IContactRepository _repo)
            {
                ContactsRepo = _repo;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
            {
                var contactList = await ContactsRepo.GetAll();
                return Ok(contactList);
            }

            [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetContacts")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(string id)
            {
                var item = await ContactsRepo.Find(id);
                if (item == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(item);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Contacts item)
            {
                if (item == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
                await ContactsRepo.Add(item);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetContacts", new { Controller = "Contacts", id = item.MobilePhone }, item);
            }

            [HttpPut("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, [FromBody] Contacts item)
            {
                if (item == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
                var contactObj = await ContactsRepo.Find(id);
                if (contactObj == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                await ContactsRepo.Update(item);
                return NoContent();
            }

            [HttpDelete("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
            {
                await ContactsRepo.Remove(id);
                return NoContent();
            }
        }
```

I have tried both type of connection string:

```
a)
"connectionstrings": {
"Default": "Server = .\\SQL2017Express; Database = ContactDB; Integrated Security = True;"
},
b)
"connectionstrings": {
"Default": "Server = .\\SQL2017Express; Database = ContactDB; User Id=sa; Password=xxxxx ; Integrated Security = True;"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have an issue connecting to the SQL instance. Unless you have more than one instance of SQL server running you would best un-install the software and install it as the default instance. This just makes configurations so much easier.

If you have SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) installed on your webserver then open and type `select @@servername` this gives the name of your actual instance.

You can also see the name in the service, I have a default instance, hence you see no name

[image: -s swich defining the instance]

Please make sure you know the performance and size limitations of SQL server express before you deploy this too production.

Have you had a look at SQL Server configuration manager (you may need to install it)

[image: Protocols]

You need to make sure that if you're not using TCP but DMA or Pipes to use the proper connection string; have you considered:

```
\\<computer_name>\pipe\MSSQL$<instance_name>
```

Have a look at [this URL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189307(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @Walter:  Follow your advice, I checked mine settings are :Sharedmemory: Enabled, Named Pipes: Disabled, TCP/IP : Disabled. I have only one Installed which is SQL2017Express.  But I still can not do the CRUD with WebApi. The connectionString is correct.

Comment: Can you log the error to a log file? 
What you do is in your ContactsController constructor you add a parameter ILogger<ContactsController > logger and save it as a class fiel. Then wrap the execution in a try catch and log  like this
catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError( e)
   }

the error, you will see the error on disk after you update your webconfig

Comment: you need to go to the webserver and look at where you published the app there will be a web.config file navigate to <aspNetCore> element in webconfig and set

stdoutLogEnabled="true" 

stdoutLogFile="D:\Inetpub\log\WebAppName"

where webname is any name you like the directory should exist and should not be available to the public as hacjers that cause errors will read it to gain infrmation on the possible attack vectors

Comment: @Walter: I have the web.config file in the Deployment Folder in C-drive. The Website in WebServer also has a web.config in AsNetCoreModule. Can I change the one in C-drive and Publish? Which One I Should change? Just set stdoutLogEnabled = true, while stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" remain the same.

Comment: @Walter I can get the log file after implemented the ILogger without change the stdoutLogEnabled = true. I dont change anything in web.config. My Error is 502.3 Bad Gateway. How to fix this problem? This error is captured by PostMan which used to test Api.

Comment: Hi Mike, it's save to change the web config as it always gets replaced when you publish. Could be a deadlock, have a look at https://blogs.iis.net/richma/502-3-bad-gateway-the-operation-timed-out-with-iis-application-request-routing-arr

Comment: @Walter, I read the link. How to open the ARR in Local IIS? Or How to configure ARR timeout? Do it in CMD prompt ? Please show the steps. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169164/discussion-between-computer-trading-and-milkbottle).